# User don't exist anymore delete user items

Tags: mysql

I want to delete users_items from users who does not exits in users anymore.
Example select users_items:

```
SELECT * FROM users_items WHERE UserID = 1
```

Example users select:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1
```

I want to delete all users_items who the user don't exists anymore. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this is to correctly set up foreign keys and use a cascading delete. That is, `users_items.UserID` should be declared as a foreign key referring to `users.id`, with the additional constraint option being `ON DELETE CASCADE`. When the parent row is deleted, it will automatically remove rows that include FKs with the cascading delete option.

More information is available here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

And searching SO has a number of answers with examples.

Comment: I cant delet it using some code like this? `insert into users_achievements (UserID, AchievementID) select UserID, 50 FROM users_items WHERE ItemID = 1452`

Comment: You could, for example, get the list of unique `UserID`s in `users_items`, and then subtract the unique `id`s found in `users`, and then delete any row that has the remaining ids. You'll notice that this is a bit complicated, and most importantly, it requires a separate query.

I know it's a bit of extra learning, but properly linking the tables with a foreign key and using cascaded deletes is by far the best solution, as it will automatically delete the `users_items` rows when the parent `user` row is deleted.

Comment: Probably a once off query like the above, but I wouldn't do so until you're able to update the table to stop the entries diverging again.

Comment: I just need to delete all users_items from users who don't exists anymore